# PHP: Is it possible to use a static variable defined earlier in the same class definition?

Tags: php

I have a php class like the following and got error saying invalid operation. I tried Sell::$a, self::$a and $this->a, Foo::$a, none of them worked. So I'm wondering if it's possible with PHP. I'm using php7.1. With Perl, there'd be no problems.

```
<?php

class Foo {
    public static $a = 1;

    public static $b = $a; /* want to assign $a to $b here */

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, since PHP supports static initialization with literals and [const](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) expression.

You can't even use `__get` since

> Member overloading only works in object context. These magic methods will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods can not be declared static.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd spent a hour or so trying to get it to work.

Comment: @Shiping oh you're welcome, i love PHP but this is one of those cases where i can't understand why they are not implementing it (there are also several proposal for this)